# YiiMongoDbSuite and combobox

Tags: php, mongodb, combobox, yii

does anybody know how to populate a combobox list with a mongodb collection?

```
$list = CHtml::listData($industryModels, '_id', 'name');
echo $form->dropDownListRow($model, 'industry_id', $list);'
```

wont work because _id is a mongoId object and toString is not automatically called. i get the following error:

```
PHP warning Illegal offset type
```

which based on the stack-trace means an object cannot be used as an array key.

so how do i get the mongoId string to use as the key in the combobox list???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not use CHtml::listData

```
$list = array();
foreach ($industryModels as $industryModel) {
    $list[$industryModel->_id] = $industryModel->name;
}
echo $form->dropDownListRow($model, 'industry_id', $list);
```

Comment: This answer will raise the same warning that Simba mentioned, MongoId objects cannot be used as array indices. You have to cast the _id to string.

Comment: this works...i called the __toString() method in the mongoId object.